# Use dynamic variable to get state value React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

So I have multiple objects in my initial state numbered from EV1-EV15, how can I grab the data in a loop? Something like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        percentage = (0.5 / this.state.EVi.timeToFull) * 100;
        newSOC = Math.round((this.state.EVi.soc + percentage) * 10) / 10;
        if (newSOC >= 100) {
            newSOC =  100;
        }
        array.push(newSOC);
    }
```

Comment: ```this.state[`EV${i}`]```

Comment: would the names after be inside the ' or outside? like this.state['EV${i}.soc']?

Comment: An array might be a better option, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.EVi` looks specifically for a property called `EVi` in `this.state`.  Instead, interpolate the index into a string and use that get the appropriate thing from state.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    const currentItem = `EV${i}`;
    percentage = (0.5 / this.state[currentItem].timeToFull) * 100;
    newSOC = Math.round((this.state[currentItem].soc + percentage) * 10) / 10;
    if (newSOC >= 100) {
        newSOC =  100;
    }
    array.push(newSOC);
}
```

Comment: works great, thanks!

Comment: @rrain good!  Glad I could help. Feel free to make this answer as the correct one if it answered your question.